# Floated div positioning bug in Chrome

Tags: html, css, forms, google-chrome

I'm writing a fairly simple navigational bar with links which float left and right. There's a search field in the mix as well, inside of an li tag which, when included, offsets the next li tag vertically down a few pixels (it may be hard to see unless you measure, but it becomes very apparent when it acquires a hover style against the bottom line of the nav bar). It happens in Chrome (30.0.1599.101), but not Safari.

Can anyone help, or suggest a fix?

[image: Login is pushed down a few pixels in Chrome.]

http://jsfiddle.net/dzSAT/14/

```
<section id="topnav">
  <div class="navcontainer">
    <nav id="topnav-main">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/" class="home activelink">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about" class=" ">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav id="topnav-account">
      <ul>
         <li class="searchbar">
          <input type="text" value="Search" />
        </li>
        <li><a href="login" class="store login">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>

section#topnav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4.1875rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
section#topnav .navcontainer {
  width: 25rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 1.6875rem;
}
section#topnav nav {
  float: left;
}
section#topnav nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
section#topnav nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 2.1875rem;
}
section#topnav nav ul li a {
  padding-bottom: 1.1875rem;
}
section#topnav ul li.searchbar {
  margin-left: 0;
}
section#topnav ul li.searchbar input {
  width: 4rem;
}
section#topnav nav#topnav-account {
  float: right;
}
section#topnav nav#topnav-account li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 2.1875rem;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
}
section#topnav {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #968c83;
  background-color: white;
}
section#topnav nav ul li a {
  color: #968c83;
}
section#topnav nav ul li a:link {
  border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
section#topnav nav ul li a:hover, section#topnav nav ul li a.activelink {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #968c83;
}

section#topnav nav ul li.searchbar {
  color: #968c83;
}
section#topnav nav ul li.searchbar input {
  color: #968c83;
}

section#topnav {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}
section#topnav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
section#topnav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the margin and padding on the `<input>`.

```
section#topnav nav ul li.searchbar input {
  color: #968c83;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

As a side note though I don't think your search box should sit inside an `<li>`.

http://jsfiddle.net/dzSAT/16/

Comment: Thanks! What do you suggest? Should it just be in its own floated div, with a ul with a single li inside next to it?

Comment: Yeah I'd float a container `<div>` right that contained a `<form>` and the login link.  Is that login link a list item if it's on it's own?  Possibly not.

Comment: I've updated your fiddle to give you a kickstart.  There's quite a few changes there as I noticed things like fixed height on containers and few other tweaks.  Have a look through the CSS and see if it helps you. http://jsfiddle.net/dzSAT/19/